# How to use graaljs ? Is there a place where to get a .jar file/files?

Tags: java, nashorn, graalvm

I use Java 8 and I use the default JavaScript Engine (Nashorn).

I would like to see how it compares with the 'highly hyped' GRAAL JS.
See:

- https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs
- https://www.graalvm.org/

particularly because I hear they want to deprecate nashorn:

- http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335

Does anybody know how to get access (easily) to graaljs ?
I was hoping to find a pom.xml or a place where to download a jar file
but not luck

Comment: GraalJS comes bundled with GraalVM. You can download a GraalVM distribution from their site: https://www.graalvm.org/downloads/ for linux and mac

Comment: thanks @JornVernee but does it mean that I can't use it on my JDK ? why ?

Comment: GraalJS needs GraalVM/Truffle to run. I believe only the AOT part of Graal is currently included in the standard JDK.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the moment there are no pre-built jars of Graal.js available outside of GraalVM. To run it on an other JDK, you can extract the jars from GraalVM or build it like this:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:graalvm/graaljs.git
$ git clone git@github.com:graalvm/mx.git
$ export PATH=$PWD/mx:$PATH
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161
$ cd graaljs/graal-js
$ mx build
```

Note that it built fine with JDK 8. It also runs on JDK 8:

```
$ mx js
> typeof([] + 1)
string
>
```

The shell works, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> exits it. The `-v` option in the previous command line shows how it launches it:

```
$ mx -v js
...
env JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161 ... \
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java -d64 -cp /tmp/graal-js/graal/sdk/mxbuild/dists/graal-sdk.jar:/tmp/graal-js/graal/truffle/mxbuild/dists/truffle-api.jar:/tmp/graal-js/graal/tools/mxbuild/dists/truffle-profiler.jar:/tmp/graal-js/graal/tools/mxbuild/dists/chromeinspector.jar:/tmp/graal-js/graal/sdk/mxbuild/dists/launcher-common.jar:/tmp/graal-js/graaljs/graal-js/mxbuild/dists/graaljs-launcher.jar:/tmp/graal-js/graal/regex/mxbuild/dists/tregex.jar:/home/gmdubosc/.mx/cache/ASM_DEBUG_ALL_702b8525fcf81454235e5e2fa2a35f15ffc0ec7e.jar:/home/gmdubosc/.mx/cache/ICU4J_6f06e820cf4c8968bbbaae66ae0b33f6a256b57f.jar:/tmp/graal-js/graaljs/graal-js/mxbuild/dists/graaljs.jar -Dtruffle.js.BindProgramResult=false -Xms2g -Xmx2g -Xss16m com.oracle.truffle.js.shell.JSLauncher
```

So it puts those jars on the classpath:

- `/tmp/graal-js/graal/sdk/mxbuild/dists/graal-sdk.jar`
- `/tmp/graal-js/graal/truffle/mxbuild/dists/truffle-api.jar`
- `/tmp/graal-js/graal/tools/mxbuild/dists/truffle-profiler.jar`
- `/tmp/graal-js/graal/tools/mxbuild/dists/chromeinspector.jar`
- `/tmp/graal-js/graal/sdk/mxbuild/dists/launcher-common.jar`
- `/tmp/graal-js/graaljs/graal-js/mxbuild/dists/graaljs-launcher.jar`
- `/tmp/graal-js/graal/regex/mxbuild/dists/tregex.jar`
- `/home/gmdubosc/.mx/cache/ASM_DEBUG_ALL_702b8525fcf81454235e5e2fa2a35f15ffc0ec7e.jar`
- `/home/gmdubosc/.mx/cache/ICU4J_6f06e820cf4c8968bbbaae66ae0b33f6a256b57f.jar`
- `/tmp/graal-js/graaljs/graal-js/mxbuild/dists/graaljs.jar`

Looking into the build artifacts we can also see `mxbuild/dists/graaljs-scriptengine.jar` which is responsible for registering Graal.js with the script engine API.

Using a small test file:

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    for (ScriptEngineFactory factory : manager.getEngineFactories()) {
      System.out.printf("%s %s: %s %s%n", factory.getLanguageName(), factory.getLanguageVersion(), factory.getEngineName(), factory.getNames());
    }
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("Graal.js");
    if (engine != null) {
      Object result = engine.eval("typeof([] + 1)");
      System.out.println(result);
    }
  }
}
```

Compiling and running it on a stock JDK 8 gives:

```
$ javac Test.java
$ java -cp . Test
ECMAScript ECMA - 262 Edition 5.1: Oracle Nashorn [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]
```

Now with Graal.js on the classpath:

```
$ java -cp /tmp/graal-js/graal/sdk/mxbuild/dists/graal-sdk.jar:/tmp/graal-js/graal/truffle/mxbuild/dists/truffle-api.jar:/tmp/graal-js/graal/regex/mxbuild/dists/tregex.jar:/home/gmdubosc/.mx/cache/ASM_DEBUG_ALL_702b8525fcf81454235e5e2fa2a35f15ffc0ec7e.jar:/home/gmdubosc/.mx/cache/ICU4J_6f06e820cf4c8968bbbaae66ae0b33f6a256b57f.jar:/tmp/graal-js/graaljs/graal-js/mxbuild/dists/graaljs.jar:/tmp/graal-js/graaljs/graal-js/mxbuild/dists/graaljs-scriptengine.jar:. Test
ECMAScript ECMA - 262 Edition 6: Graal.js [Graal.js, graal.js, Graal-js, graal-js, Graal.JS, Graal-JS, GraalJS, GraalJSPolyglot, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]
ECMAScript ECMA - 262 Edition 5.1: Oracle Nashorn [nashorn, Nashorn, null, null, null, null, null, null]
string
```

(note that this command line ignores `truffle-profiler`, `chromeinspector`, `launcher-common` and `graaljs-launcher` which are not necessary when using Graal.js through the script engine.)

Since the standard JDK 8 doesn't support JVMCI and/or the Graal compiler, there will be no JIT compilations for JS so don't expect much in terms of performance. To get performance you need a special JDK 8 or JDK 9+ as well as the Graal-Truffle bindings.

Comment: d thanks for the long explanation I will test it out and if right I will choose it as the correct answer

Comment: Why is `mx` bring used to run the interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

ok, sadly I will answer my own question.
After a bit of research I found out that I could not get it running on java 8 and anyway there is no .jar (and neither I can manually create it) for graaljs

details are here:

https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/blob/master/docs/Building.md