# IllegalStateException: No language and polyglot implementation was found on the classpath. Make sure the truffle-api.jar is on the classpath

Tags: java, java-11, graalvm

> ```
> IllegalStateException: No language and polyglot implementation was found on the
> classpath. Make sure the truffle-api.jar is on the classpath.
> ```

I wanted to use GraalVM in my Java project.

I added this dependency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
  <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-rc10</version>
</dependency>
```

but apparently that's not enough.

What else do I have to do to fix this error?

Comment: Why did you add that specific dependency only? What did you read to think that was enough? --- Anyway, do what it says, find the dependency for truffle-api.jar and add that too.

Comment: There's a section called "Running Graal.js on a stock JDK**
" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52200711/1087978

Comment: What do you mean by "use GraalVM in my Java project."?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had to add all these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
  <artifactId>js</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-rc10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
  <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-rc10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.graalvm.truffle</groupId>
  <artifactId>truffle-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-rc10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: OMG so unobvious. Do they have it somewhere in documentation updated?

Comment: its 2022, still no :) @o_nix

Answer (score 4):

```
implementation 'org.graalvm.sdk:graal-sdk:20.1.0'
implementation 'org.graalvm.truffle:truffle-api:20.1.0'
implementation 'org.graalvm.js:js:20.1.0'
```

Comment: Good Gradle alternative