# GraalVM - No language and polyglot implementation was found on the classpath

Tags: java, maven, bukkit, graalvm

I'm trying to use GraalVM inside a project to add simple scripting capabilities. I'm using Maven for dependency management to load Graal's base dependencies. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>cx.matthew</groupId>
  <artifactId>graaltest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <graalvm.version>19.0.2</graalvm.version>
    <compiler.dir>${project.build.directory}/compiler</compiler.dir>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>papermc</id>
      <url>https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>graal-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
      <artifactId>js</artifactId>
      <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
      <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
      <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>profiler</artifactId>
      <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>chromeinspector</artifactId>
      <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.truffle</groupId>
      <artifactId>truffle-api</artifactId>
      <version>19.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.destroystokyo.paper</groupId>
      <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

And here is my code calling Graal:

```
package cx.matthew.graaltest;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Context;

public class GraalTestPlugin extends JavaPlugin {

  @Override
  public void onEnable() {
    Context context = Context.create();
    context.eval("js", "console.log(\"hi!!!\");");
  }

}
```

While this should work as far as I can tell, when running it, it outputs the following error:

```
[19:25:16 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling GraalTest v1.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No language and polyglot implementation was found on the classpath. Make sure the truffle-api.jar is on the classpath.
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.noPolyglotImplementationFound(Engine.java:800) ~[?:?]
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.buildEngine(Engine.java:732) ~[?:?]
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$Builder.build(Engine.java:505) ~[?:?]
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context$Builder.build(Context.java:1304) ~[?:?]
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.create(Context.java:697) ~[?:?]
    at cx.matthew.graaltest.GraalTestPlugin.onEnable(GraalTestPlugin.java:10) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:338) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:419) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:464) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:378) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:854) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:610) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:54) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:159) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:736) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:698) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:457) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:419) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1061) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:905) ~[patched_1.14.2.jar:git-Paper-97]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Now, of course the suggested solution for this as the error says is to include truffle-api.jar in the classpath, however since this is running in a plugin environment, it is less than ideal to have end users of this plugin have to set up their classpath manually. Shading in the truffle-api Maven dependency doesn't seem to work, which is usually the solution to something like this.

There have been some existing proposed solutions. The first I came across was in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54416106/3483261), but as you can see in my pom.xml, all of these dependencies are already included.

The other solution I've seen (as well as the problem) are outlined in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/issues/125#issuecomment-500654731), but while I can confirm the modified META-INF/truffle/language file is in my final jar, it doesn't seem to be working. This is the file that is output in the jar:

```
language1.characterMimeType.0=application/tregex
language1.className=com.oracle.truffle.regex.RegexLanguage
language1.id=regex
language1.implementationName=
language1.interactive=false
language1.internal=true
language1.name=REGEX
language1.version=0.1

language2.characterMimeType.0=application/javascript
language2.characterMimeType.1=application/javascript+module
language2.characterMimeType.2=text/javascript
language2.className=com.oracle.truffle.js.lang.JavaScriptLanguage
language2.defaultMimeType=application/javascript
language2.dependentLanguage.0=regex
language2.fileTypeDetector0=com.oracle.truffle.js.lang.JSFileTypeDetector
language2.id=js
language2.implementationName=GraalVM JavaScript
language2.interactive=true
language2.internal=false
language2.name=JavaScript
language2.version=inherit
```

So, I'm kind of at a loss for what to do at this point. Does anyone have any ideas for how to solve this issue?

Comment: Some updates: it appears that the issue actually isn't with how Graal is loading language implementations, but with how Graal is using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` as the class loader, but Bukkit uses its own custom classloader as a plugin system. As far as I can tell, there's no way to change the way that Graal loads classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now, the best way I've found of getting around this is to swap the context ClassLoader out for the correct one and then swap it back:

```
ClassLoader oldCl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
// Insert Graal code here
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(oldCl);
```

You can even set it up as a callback so you don't have to have that same code over and over:

```
private void runInPluginContext(ContextCallback callback) {
  ClassLoader oldCl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
  callback.call();
  Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(oldCl);
}

interface ContextCallback {

  void call();

}
```

And run it using:

```
runInPluginContext(() -> {
  // Insert Graal code here
});
```

Obviously this is not ideal because it requires you to change context every time you call Graal code. If anyone has a better solution, I'd love to see it!