# Quarkus build native with graalvm polyglot embed script language runtime error

Tags: gradle, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Quarkus and Graalvm version

```
quarkusPluginId=io.quarkus
quarkusPluginVersion=2.15.3.Final
quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus.platform
quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-bom
quarkusPlatformVersion=2.15.3.Final
graalVmVersion=22.3.0
```

I want use Quarkus with Graalvm embed script language and native image

*dependencies*

```
dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-config-yaml'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    implementation 'org.graalvm.sdk:graal-sdk:${graalVmVersion}'
    implementation 'org.graalvm.js:js:${graalVmVersion}'
    implementation 'org.graalvm.truffle:truffle-api:${graalVmVersion}'
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
}
```

*build script*

```bash
./gradlew build -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.additional-build-args="--language:js"
```

When I use these dependencies, everything just work.

But when I add hibernate dependency

```
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-h2'
```

Run the build script will show me this error

```bash
> Task :quarkusBuild

[2/7] Performing analysis...  [**]                                                                      (29.6s @ 3.50GB)
  27,299 (94.12%) of 29,005 classes reachable
  45,307 (64.02%) of 70,775 fields reachable
 144,092 (65.40%) of 220,308 methods reachable
     700 classes,   125 fields, and 3,347 methods registered for reflection
       1 native library: -framework CoreServices

Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:

 com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from language option 'icu4j@file:///Users/d/.sdkman/candidates/java/22.3.r17-grl/languages/icu4j/' with 'com.ibm.icu' and from language option 'js@file:///Users/d/.sdkman/candidates/java/22.3.r17-grl/languages/js/' with 'com.ibm.icu'). To see why com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug
com.ibm.icu.text.Collator the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from language option 'icu4j@file:///Users/d/.sdkman/candidates/java/22.3.r17-grl/languages/icu4j/' with 'com.ibm.icu' and from language option 'js@file:///Users/d/.sdkman/candidates/java/22.3.r17-grl/languages/js/' with 'com.ibm.icu'). To see why com.ibm.icu.text.Collator got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=com.ibm.icu.text.Collator
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
To see how the classes got initialized, use --trace-class-initialization=com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug,com.ibm.icu.text.Collator
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from language option 'icu4j@file:///Users/d/.sdkman/candidates/java/22.3.r17-grl/languages/icu4j/' with 'com.ibm.icu' and from language option 'js@file:///Users/d/.sdkman/candidates/java/22.3.r17-grl/languages/js/' with 'com.ibm.icu'). To see why com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug
com.ibm.icu.text.Collator the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from language option 'icu4j@file:///Users/d/.sdkman/candidates/java/22.3.r17-grl/languages/icu4j/' with 'com.ibm.icu' and from language option 'js@file:///Users/d/.sdkman/candidates/java/22.3.r17-grl/languages/js/' with 'com.ibm.icu'). To see why com.ibm.icu.text.Collator got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=com.ibm.icu.text.Collator
To see how the classes got initialized, use --trace-class-initialization=com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug,com.ibm.icu.text.Collator
    at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:73)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ProvenSafeClassInitializationSupport.checkDelayedInitialization(ProvenSafeClassInitializationSupport.java:273)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationFeature.duringAnalysis(ClassInitializationFeature.java:164)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$10(NativeImageGenerator.java:748)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:85)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$11(NativeImageGenerator.java:748)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.AbstractAnalysisEngine.runAnalysis(AbstractAnalysisEngine.java:162)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:745)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:578)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:535)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:403)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:580)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:610)
                        3.8s (9.3% of total time) in 26 GCs | Peak RSS: 6.03GB | CPU load: 3.93
========================================================================================================================
Failed generating 'demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner' after 40.3s.
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1


> Task :quarkusBuild FAILED

Execution failed for task ':quarkusBuild'.
> io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep$ImageGenerationFailureException: Image generation failed. Exit code: 1
    at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.imageGenerationFailed(NativeImageBuildStep.java:421)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:262)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

So I add a arguments in build command

```bash
./gradlew build -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.additional-build-args="--language:js"  -Dquarkus.native.additional-build-args="--initialize-at-build-time=com.ibm.icu"
```

And this build command just work, but when I run the built binary and access api that use graalvm polyglot sdk, in runtime will show error

```bash
2023-01-14 13:17:10,847 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) HTTP Request to /hello failed, error id: 36b4f719-2397-4766-ac15-c221327bf2c4-1: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No language and polyglot implementation was found on the classpath. Make sure a language is added to the classpath (e.g., native-image --language:js).
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.noPolyglotImplementationFound(Engine.java:1014)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.createHostAccess(Engine.java:1004)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$Builder.build(Engine.java:626)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context$Builder.build(Context.java:1851)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.create(Context.java:976)
        at com.example.ExampleResource.hello(ExampleResource.java:16)
        at com.example.ExampleResource$quarkusrestinvoker$hello_e747664148511e1e5212d3e0f4b40d45c56ab8a1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:114)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)

2023-01-14 13:17:10,876 ERROR [org.jbo.res.rea.com.cor.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext] (executor-thread-0) Request failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No language and polyglot implementation was found on the classpath. Make sure a language is added to the classpath (e.g., native-image --language:js).
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.noPolyglotImplementationFound(Engine.java:1014)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.createHostAccess(Engine.java:1004)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$Builder.build(Engine.java:626)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context$Builder.build(Context.java:1851)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.create(Context.java:976)
        at com.example.ExampleResource.hello(ExampleResource.java:16)
        at com.example.ExampleResource$quarkusrestinvoker$hello_e747664148511e1e5212d3e0f4b40d45c56ab8a1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:114)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)

2023-01-14 13:17:11,056 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) HTTP Request to /hello failed, error id: 36b4f719-2397-4766-ac15-c221327bf2c4-2: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No language and polyglot implementation was found on the classpath. Make sure a language is added to the classpath (e.g., native-image --language:js).
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.noPolyglotImplementationFound(Engine.java:1014)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.createHostAccess(Engine.java:1004)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$Builder.build(Engine.java:626)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context$Builder.build(Context.java:1851)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.create(Context.java:976)
        at com.example.ExampleResource.hello(ExampleResource.java:16)
        at com.example.ExampleResource$quarkusrestinvoker$hello_e747664148511e1e5212d3e0f4b40d45c56ab8a1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:114)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)

2023-01-14 13:17:11,058 ERROR [org.jbo.res.rea.com.cor.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext] (executor-thread-0) Request failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No language and polyglot implementation was found on the classpath. Make sure a language is added to the classpath (e.g., native-image --language:js).
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.noPolyglotImplementationFound(Engine.java:1014)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.createHostAccess(Engine.java:1004)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$Builder.build(Engine.java:626)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context$Builder.build(Context.java:1851)
        at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.create(Context.java:976)
        at com.example.ExampleResource.hello(ExampleResource.java:16)
        at com.example.ExampleResource$quarkusrestinvoker$hello_e747664148511e1e5212d3e0f4b40d45c56ab8a1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:114)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)
```

It make me confused and how to resolve this problem

Use graalvm embed sciprt language in quarkus

Comment: have you tried to add dependencies as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54416106/175554)

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/30380), using GraalVM plolyglot is not something Quarkus supports